# How to implement Java interface under JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I would like my native code does the exact same thing as following Java code on Android:

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.setClassName("com.example.someservice", "com.example.someservice.service"); 
bindService(i, clientConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

But `clientConnection` is a [ServiceConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) interface in Java. How could I implement the interface in c native code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use Binder because it's not part of the NDK APIs.

Look in the NDK docs/STABLE-APIS.html for the full list of stable APIs, and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/1QmVRrNckfM) for an explicit comment by David Turner (the NDK maintainer) that Binder is not a supported API.

Your options are:

- Use some other form of IPC in native code - for example a UNIX domain socket
- Do it in Java, using the normal `Service` and AIDL facilities of the Android SDK. If you wish to combine this with native code you may be able to call up to Java from native code using JNI.
- (Not recommended) Copy the relevant libraries and headers from an Android Open-Source Project; build into your NDK project; and use the APIs. However this is not officially supported and is extremely likely to break your application in future releases because Google are under no obligation to maintain compatibility in such libraries (and frequently do not). It's also very difficult, since you need to find some way to register the service such that the client can find it.